# How to detect top right bottom left screen area JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

How to detect top right bottom left screen area JavaScript? I have four arrow for slider but I wanna display only when mouse hover on particular area.

```
$('.container').mousemove(function (e) {
if (e.clientY < $('.container').height() / 2) {
    console.log('top');
} else {
    console.log('bottom');
}
if (e.client X < $('.container').width() / 2) {
    console.log('left');
} else {
    console.log('right');
}
});
```

Comment: I would just make an element that covers the whole area you are checking for, but make it transparent. Then when you detect the mouseover, you can show the element. I know this does not answer your question but it is just how I would solve the problem :)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: thanks max i will try that.

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2m5s194y/

Comment: thanks @ChrisG this will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you consider a CSS `:hover` suggestion? It may be simpler. Added font awesome arrows as example.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: lightgray;
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: lightgray;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: lightgray;
}
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: lightgray;
}
.top:hover,
.left:hover,
.right:hover,
.bottom:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: gray;
}
.top:hover i,
.left:hover i,
.right:hover i,
.bottom:hover i {
  display: block;
}
i.fa {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
i.fa.fa-arrow-right,
i.fa.fa-arrow-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="top"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></div>
<div class="left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></div>
<div class="right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
<div class="bottom"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></div>
```

Comment: @bk129 This is a great option. Let the browser handle the sizing, then you can attach a listener for the hover event to any given element if you need more advanced behavior. Using :hover and acting on the hover event should be _much_ less of a workload than evaluating the mouse's coordinates _every time it moves at all_.

Answer (score 0):

```
// define the rectangular areas
var areas = {
    top: [0, 0, 500, 100], // [startX, startY, endX, endY]
    left: [0, 0, 100, 500],
    right: [100, 0, 500, 500],
    bottom: [0, 400, 500, 500]
};

function getArea(x, y) {
    for (var key in areas) {
        var area = areas[key];
        if (x <= area[0] && x >= area[2] && y <= area[1] && y >= area[3]) return key;
    }
    return null;
}

$('.container').mousemove(function (e) {
    console.clear && console.clear();
    console.log(getArea(e.clientX, e.clientY));
});
```